# Create and populate a Pandas data frame columns using two existing columns

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame has  4 columns and looks as below.

#### What I have:

```
ID  start_date  end_date    active
1,111   6/30/2015   8/6/1904    1 to 10
1,111   6/28/2016   3/30/1905   1 to 10
1,111   7/31/2017   6/6/1905    1 to 10
1,111   7/31/2018   6/6/1905    1 to 9
1,111   5/31/2019   12/4/1904   1 to 9
3,033   3/31/2015   5/18/1908   3 to 7
3,033   3/31/2016   11/24/1905  3 to 7
3,033   3/31/2017   1/20/1906   3 to 7
3,033   3/31/2018   1/8/1906    2 to 7
3,033   4/4/2019    2200,0  2 to 8
```

I want to generate 10 more columns based on the value of column "active" as below. Is there a way to populate this efficiently.

#### What I want to achieve

```
ID  start_date  end_date    active  Type 1  Type 2  Type 3  Type 4  Type 5  Type 6  Type 7  Type 8  Type 9  Type 10
1,111   6/30/2015   8/6/1904    1 to 10 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1,111   6/28/2016   3/30/1905   1 to 10 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1,111   7/31/2017   6/6/1905    1 to 10 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1,111   7/31/2018   6/6/1905    1 to 9  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
1,111   5/31/2019   12/4/1904   1 to 9  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
3,033   3/31/2015   5/18/1908   3 to 7          1   1   1   1   1           
3,033   3/31/2016   11/24/1905  3 to 7          1   1   1   1   1           
3,033   3/31/2017   1/20/1906   3 to 7          1   1   1   1   1           
3,033   3/31/2018   1/8/1906    2 to 7      1   1   1   1   1   1           
3,033   4/4/2019    2200,0  2 to 8      1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: I am really curious, what solution is faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function with `np.arange`:

```
def f(x):
    a = list(map(int, x.split(' to ')))
    return pd.Series(1, index= np.arange(a[0], a[1] + 1))

df = df.join(df['active'].apply(f).add_prefix('Type '))
print (df)
      ID start_date    end_date   active  Type 1  Type 2  Type 3  Type 4  \
0  1,111  6/30/2015    8/6/1904  1 to 10     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0   
1  1,111  6/28/2016   3/30/1905  1 to 10     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0   
2  1,111  7/31/2017    6/6/1905  1 to 10     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0   
3  1,111  7/31/2018    6/6/1905   1 to 9     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0   
4  1,111  5/31/2019   12/4/1904   1 to 9     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0   
5  3,033  3/31/2015   5/18/1908   3 to 7     NaN     NaN     1.0     1.0   
6  3,033  3/31/2016  11/24/1905   3 to 7     NaN     NaN     1.0     1.0   
7  3,033  3/31/2017   1/20/1906   3 to 7     NaN     NaN     1.0     1.0   
8  3,033  3/31/2018    1/8/1906   2 to 7     NaN     1.0     1.0     1.0   
9  3,033   4/4/2019      2200,0   2 to 8     NaN     1.0     1.0     1.0   

   Type 5  Type 6  Type 7  Type 8  Type 9  Type 10  
0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0      1.0  
1     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0      1.0  
2     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0      1.0  
3     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0      NaN  
4     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0      NaN  
5     1.0     1.0     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN  
6     1.0     1.0     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN  
7     1.0     1.0     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN  
8     1.0     1.0     1.0     NaN     NaN      NaN  
9     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     NaN      NaN
```

Similar:

```
def f(x):
    a = list(map(int, x.split(' to ')))
    return pd.Series(1, index= np.arange(a[0], a[1] + 1))

df = df.join(df['active'].apply(f).add_prefix('Type ').fillna(0).astype(int))
print (df)
      ID start_date    end_date   active  Type 1  Type 2  Type 3  Type 4  \
0  1,111  6/30/2015    8/6/1904  1 to 10       1       1       1       1   
1  1,111  6/28/2016   3/30/1905  1 to 10       1       1       1       1   
2  1,111  7/31/2017    6/6/1905  1 to 10       1       1       1       1   
3  1,111  7/31/2018    6/6/1905   1 to 9       1       1       1       1   
4  1,111  5/31/2019   12/4/1904   1 to 9       1       1       1       1   
5  3,033  3/31/2015   5/18/1908   3 to 7       0       0       1       1   
6  3,033  3/31/2016  11/24/1905   3 to 7       0       0       1       1   
7  3,033  3/31/2017   1/20/1906   3 to 7       0       0       1       1   
8  3,033  3/31/2018    1/8/1906   2 to 7       0       1       1       1   
9  3,033   4/4/2019      2200,0   2 to 8       0       1       1       1   

   Type 5  Type 6  Type 7  Type 8  Type 9  Type 10  
0       1       1       1       1       1        1  
1       1       1       1       1       1        1  
2       1       1       1       1       1        1  
3       1       1       1       1       1        0  
4       1       1       1       1       1        0  
5       1       1       1       0       0        0  
6       1       1       1       0       0        0  
7       1       1       1       0       0        0  
8       1       1       1       0       0        0  
9       1       1       1       1       0        0
```

Another non loop solution - idea is remove duplicates, create new rows with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add missing columns and last add `1` by multiple [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)ed values:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('active', drop=False)
        .pop('active')
        .drop_duplicates()
        .str.get_dummies(' to '))

df1.columns = df1.columns.astype(int)
df1 = df1.reindex(columns=np.arange(df1.columns.min(),df1.columns.max() + 1), fill_value=0)
df1 = (df1.cumsum(axis=1) * df1.iloc[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1)).clip_upper(1)
print (df1)
         1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
active                                         
1 to 10   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1 to 9    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
3 to 7    0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
2 to 7    0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
2 to 8    0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0

df = df.join(df1.add_prefix('Type '), on='active')
print (df)
```

---

```
      ID start_date    end_date   active  Type 1  Type 2  Type 3  Type 4  \
0  1,111  6/30/2015    8/6/1904  1 to 10       1       1       1       1   
1  1,111  6/28/2016   3/30/1905  1 to 10       1       1       1       1   
2  1,111  7/31/2017    6/6/1905  1 to 10       1       1       1       1   
3  1,111  7/31/2018    6/6/1905   1 to 9       1       1       1       1   
4  1,111  5/31/2019   12/4/1904   1 to 9       1       1       1       1   
5  3,033  3/31/2015   5/18/1908   3 to 7       0       0       1       1   
6  3,033  3/31/2016  11/24/1905   3 to 7       0       0       1       1   
7  3,033  3/31/2017   1/20/1906   3 to 7       0       0       1       1   
8  3,033  3/31/2018    1/8/1906   2 to 7       0       1       1       1   
9  3,033   4/4/2019      2200,0   2 to 8       0       1       1       1   

   Type 5  Type 6  Type 7  Type 8  Type 9  Type 10  
0       1       1       1       1       1        1  
1       1       1       1       1       1        1  
2       1       1       1       1       1        1  
3       1       1       1       1       1        0  
4       1       1       1       1       1        0  
5       1       1       1       0       0        0  
6       1       1       1       0       0        0  
7       1       1       1       0       0        0  
8       1       1       1       0       0        0  
9       1       1       1       1       0        0
```

Comment: @Anu - I try explain more - green mark is possible get to only one answer. So I see first my solution was accepted and then another one, so not sure if you want select both of not. If want select another answer it is absolutely fine, it is up to you which solution working for you better. Nice day!

Comment: Non-loop worked for me better. This is due to some values in active column are not range (3 to 7) but just a single number.

Comment: @Anu - So now I am confused a bit - my solution is better and accepted another one answer? Or my solutions working nice, but another `piRSquared` solution is faster or better of nicer for you ;)?

Comment: Changed it. I just noticed I ticked on the other solution, which worked too but throwing an error for only integer values.

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(s):
  a, b = map(int, s.split('to'))
  return '|'.join(map(str, range(a, b + 1)))

df.drop('active', 1).join(df.active.apply(f).str.get_dummies().add_prefix('Type '))

      ID start_date    end_date  Type 1  Type 10  Type 2  Type 3  Type 4  Type 5  Type 6  Type 7  Type 8  Type 9
0  1,111  6/30/2015    8/6/1904       1        1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
1  1,111  6/28/2016   3/30/1905       1        1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
2  1,111  7/31/2017    6/6/1905       1        1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
3  1,111  7/31/2018    6/6/1905       1        0       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
4  1,111  5/31/2019   12/4/1904       1        0       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
5  3,033  3/31/2015   5/18/1908       0        0       0       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
6  3,033  3/31/2016  11/24/1905       0        0       0       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
7  3,033  3/31/2017   1/20/1906       0        0       0       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
8  3,033  3/31/2018    1/8/1906       0        0       1       1       1       1       1       1       0       0
9  3,033   4/4/2019      2200,0       0        0       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       0
```